# Как лучше всего использовать else-блок при по обработке исключений?

Tags: python

При написании кода по обработке помимо необязательного `finally` блока есть еще и необязательный `else` блок. Напомню, что этот блок кода выполняется если `try` блок завершился успешно, без летящих исключений.

Вопрос: Зачем нужен `else` блок, если все можно поместить в `try` блок?

Об этом вопросе уже было обсуждение в англоязычной версии SO: [Python try-else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/855759/python-try-else). Но опять же, на мой взгляд, нет ясного и конкретного ответа, когда без `else` блока действительно нельзя обойтись и лучше с ним.

Пока мое понимание на уровне правила(сформулировал сам, независимо от кого-либо): Если понадобился `else` блок, то код функции сложноват. Код в `else` следует поместить в отдельный метод и вызывать не в том куске кода, где хочется написать `else`, а уровнем по выше, т.е. более высокоуровневой функции.

Comment: Дак ведь, `finally` выполняет блок инструкций в любом случае, было ли исключение, или нет (применима, когда нужно непременно что-то сделать, к примеру, закрыть файл). Инструкция `else` выполняется в том случае, если исключения не было (например, в случае, когда вам необходимо залогировать успешность выполнения действия, описанного в блоке `try`).

Comment: @StateItPrimitive, залогировать ведь можно и в try после того как возможно-проблемная часть выполнилась без исключений

Comment: @gil9red Я так понимаю, что для наглядности, дабы не раздувать размеры блока `try` и чтобы не встраивать логику обработки успешности выполнения действия непосредственно в `try` (хотя, с другой стороны, с таким же успехом, эту логику можно было вынести в отдельную функцию и встроить в конец `try`). Но это все лишь мнение со стороны, т.к. я не являются python-программистом.

Comment: @StateItPrimitive, просто я после прочтения мануалов об этом задумывался, и пришел к мнению, что и без `else` код выглядит понятным

Comment: @gil9red: Полностью согласен! Для меня код функции должен помещаться в `try` блок. И либо функция решила задачу ради, которой написана, либо нет! А в случае раздельных `try` и `else` код размазывается и внимание "читателя" рассеивается

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Давайте сравнивать два варианта:

1. Выполнение каких-то действий в самом конце `try`;
2. Выполнение этих же действий в отдельном блоке `else`.

Допустим, это добавление записи в лог.

В первом случае, во время логирования может возникнуть исключение, которое будет поймано блоком `except`. Но что, если вы *не хотите* обрабатывать исключения логирования в этом месте? Тогда на помощь приходит блок `else`:

```
try:
    # код, который может бросить исключение IOError
except IOError:
    # обработка исключения
else:
    # логирование успеха операции из try
    # здесь также может возникнуть IOError, но он не поймается в except
finally:
    # код, который выполнится в любом случае
```

Можно также считать `else` противоположностью `except` — частью языка, введённой для полноты возможностей. `try` и `finally` выполняются всегда. `except` — только при возникновении исключений. `else` — только когда нет исключений. Получается полное множество.

Comment: Да, согласен, что во время операции логирования тоже может возникнуть исключение, но разве не лучше, если она будет извещать об этом более точным способом? К примеру летящим `WriteToLogException` ? Пока я склоняюсь к мысли, что если потребовалось использовать `else` блок, то функция слишком сложная и ее нужно разбить на две и более и сделать более четче в плане понимания ее работы

Comment: @sys_dev Вы не всегда контроллируете код, в котором может возникнуть исключение. Например, `WriteToLogException` наследует `IOError`, а код в `try` бросает `IOError`. В таком случае, разделить обработку этих двух исключений можно либо при помощи `else`, либо с помощью других изощрений с кодом. Что удобнее и читабельнее — выбирать автору кода. Важно, что есть выбор и техническая возможность. Как по мне, наличие `else` — плюс, а не минус.

Comment: Но ведь никто не принуждает наследовать `WriteToLogException` от`IOError`. Тогда оно полетит на уровень выше к более высокоуровневому коду. Да и, если честно, логирование не должно бросать исключений. Это лишь вспомогательный инструмент поддержки ПО, но не основной для чего создают ПО

Comment: @sys_dev Во-первых, логирование — только пример. Во-вторых, повторюсь, код, который вы вызываете — далеко не всегда является кодом, который вы можете изменить. Стандартный логгер python бросает именно `IOError`, если по какой-то причине не может писать в файл.

Comment: Да, есть такие куски кода, которые я не могу изменить, но ведь я могу поместить такие куски обернуть. Мы ведь работаем с кодом, а не с бетоном.

Comment: @sys_dev думаю, что здесь уже дело в стиле программирования и личных предпочтениях автора кода. Можно сделать как вы, а можно использовать `else`. Выбор — за программистом.

Comment: @sys_dev: следует подчеркнуть, что `try` блок должен содержать как можно меньше кода, чтобы уменьшить вероятность, что неожиданное исключение поймается. Размещение кода из `else`-блока в `try`-блоке может приводить к багам, например: `try: long_function(timeout=1) except TimeoutError: handle_timeout() else: next_thing()` Если `next_thing()` может выкинуть `TimeoutError`, то её нельзя поднимать в `try`-блок. Дело не в стиле программирования или личных предпочтениях автора — дело в корректности кода.

Comment: @jfs: У Вас возможно есть блог. Можете развернуть свою мысль?

Comment: @sys_dev: я предпочитаю отвечать на вопросы на Stack Overflow.